# One folder is not showing in linux but shows in windows

Tags: external-hard-drive

I have a 2 Tb external drive my passport ultra. and it is formatted in ntfs. it have multiple folders, but content of one folder (one with the biggest amount of data) does not shows in linux but shows in windows.

folder is visible, and content of other folder is visible in linux.
and i check for drive errors in windows and it says drive is fine.

what is the solution

Comment: Please edit your question with the name of the folder, Linux distribution, and Linux distribution version.

Comment: problem solved. it was drive  error. used ntfsfix to remove error.

Comment: Write an answer your own question below with additional details.  Someone else might have the same issue someday.